# Datatable Search for filter

Tags: php, datatables

I have this list of data in my datatables. However, i have problem when i'm using the search filter box. My data in the datatables consist of character symbol like &,%,#,$. whenever i type this character, it shown no data. That's the current problem that occurred. Is there solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: `$` works on their own site: http://www.datatables.net/ did you change any configuration? Here is more documentation: http://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html

Comment: currently i'm using the default that i get from there. did the symbol & works?

Comment: Are u sure the character is in your dataset? If so can you create a snippet?